# how to cancel the coroutines jobs after timeout

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, withcontext, withtimeoutornull

Having a suspend function `fetchData()`.  What it does is to launch a few jobs in the `withContext`, so that it will only return after the jobs are complete (which are: `suspend fun getData(): Boolean`).

And also want if it times out then return false from the function.

The problem is when it times out, with `withTimeoutOrNull(500) { jobs.joinAll() }`, it stuck in the function not exit.

The log shows it times out, also clearly points to last line of the code before exit the function:

```
     E/+++: +++ in fetchData() after null = withTimeoutOrNull(500), jobs.sizs: 3
     E/+++: +++ --- exit fetchData(), allFresh: false
```

But the caller of the `fetchData()` gets stuck and not return from the `fetchData()`.

This is the caller:

```
suspend fun caller() {
    var allGood = fetchData()

    // never return to here

    Log.e("+++", "+++ caller(), after allGood: $allGood = fetchData()")
    ...
}
```

Below is the code,  how to cancel the jobs if timeout?

```
suspend fun fetchData(): Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

    var allFresh = requestHandlertMap.size > 0
    if (!allFresh) {
        allFresh
    } else {
        val handlers = requestHandlertMap.values.toList()
        val jobs: List<Deferred<Boolean>> = handlers.map {handler->
            async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                if (isActive) handler.getData() else true
                        .also {
                            Log.e("+++", "+++ in fetchData():async{} after handler.getData()")
                        }
            }
        }
        val result = withTimeoutOrNull(500) { jobs.joinAll() }

        Log.e("+++", "+++ in fetchData() after $result = withTimeoutOrNull(500), jobs.size: ${jobs.size} ")

        if (result != null) {
            allFresh = jobs.all { deferred ->
                deferred.await()
            }
            Log.e("+++", "+++ +++ +++ in fetchData() call  onDataReady(), allFresh: $allFresh = deferred.await() ")
            onDataReady()
        } else {

            // how to cancel the jobs ???

            //jobs.all { deferred ->
                //deferred.cancelChildren()
            //}

            allFresh = false
        }
        allFresh
                .also {
                    Log.e("+++", "+++ --- exit fetchData(), allFresh: $allFresh  ")
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some reading/trying,  it seems having a few issues with the implementation.

1. Somehow the `CoroutineStart.LAZY`  causes a strange behavior, that the `async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY)`
   start sequentially (expecting they should start to be concurrently), so that when it times out it stuck in the function (guess because it is wrapped in the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and not all child coroutines are completed -- if there is someone not start yet).

Remove the `start = CoroutineStart.LAZY` makes it returning from the `fun fetchData()`

```
val jobs: List<Deferred<Boolean>> = handlers.map {handler->
            async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
                if (isActive) handler.getData() else true
                        .also {
                            Log.e("+++", "+++ in fetchData():async{} after handler.getData()")
                        }
            }
        }
```

2. the `suspend fun getData(): Boolean`  was not implemented `cooperate to be cancellable`, which may causes it still stay in the function until all children are completed although timeout has already happened.
3. seems it still need to call the `deferred.cancelChildren()`, otherwise they are not cancelled by the `withTimeoutNotNull()`,  not sure why, isnt it supposed to cancel the jobs automatically?

the change made

```
private suspend fun fetchData(): Boolean {
        var allFresh: Boolean? = requestHandlertMap.size > 0
        if (allFresh == true) {

            val handlers = requestHandlertMap.values.toList()
            val jobs: List<Deferred<Boolean>> = handlers.map {
                serviceScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) { handler -> if (isActive) handler.getData() else false }
            }
            allFresh = withTimeoutOrNull(3000) {
                try {
                    jobs.awaitAll().all { it }
                } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                    false
                }
            }

            if (allFresh != null) {
                onDataReady()
            } else {
                jobs.map { deferred -> deferred.cancelChildren() }
            }
        }
        return allFresh == true // allFresh = {null, true, false}
    }
```

ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305044/kotlin-coroutine-withtimeout-does-not-cancel-when-using-withcontext-to-get-non-b) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55085363/launch-a-number-of-coroutines-and-join-them-all-with-timeout-without-cancelling)